# SELECT value don't want to be inserted into table through INSER INTO table_name VALUES(SELECT...). ANY TIPS?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

So I have a table and into that table I want to insert some values. And everything is working but when I come to my subquery:

```sql
INSERT INTO `gb.uträckning`(of_bostäder_objekt, typ_av_objekt, objekttyp, antal_kvm, relativt_hyrestal_bastal)
VALUES(22105859, 'B', 'B2K' , 64,
(SELECT
IF(t1.typ_av_objekt = 'B' OR typ_av_objekt = 'NyB', t1.antal_kvm + 
IF(t1.balkong_uteplats_saknas = 1, t2.`2`, IF(t1.balkong_uteplats_saknas = 2, t2.`1`, IF(t1.balkong_uteplats_saknas = 3, t2.`3`, t2.`2`))), NULL)
FROM `gb.uträckning` t1, `nh.lägenhetstyp` t2
WHERE t1.objekttyp = t2.lägenhetstyp));
```

So my subquery return the value I want but don't want to be inserted into the table. I don't get an error. But if my query return more than 1 value then an error pop up saying "Subquery returns more than 1 row".[My Table, value should be inserted into column_name 'relativt_hyrestal_bastal'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDqUj.png)[What my subquery returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7lBH.png)

I have tried to change the equal operator in Where clause but get an syntax error or that my subquery returns more than 1 row. I have also tried to assign the selected value into an varaible and then into insert but it doesn't work. My query returns what I want but the problem is that it does not want to insert it into the table and it don't want to insert if my query returns more than 1 value. Because I want to use this subquery in a trigger later on to use for multiple rows at once.

Comment: Not sure if you want to insert multiple records when your sub query returns multiple values? Else you can just say `LIMIT 1 to your query`

Comment: OK, I understand. I will look into that but the current problem is that my query is using data as you see in the query from the table `gb.uträckning` and `nh.lägenhetstyp`. I want to like insert the value that my query returns into `gb.uträckning`. But I can't insert to a row that exists so my question is, can I use update?